# When rounding swift double it shows different numbers

Tags: swift, double, rounding

When I got two numbers, like 5.085 and 70.085. My code rounds the first number to 5.09, but the second one it goes to 70.08. For some reason, when making `let aux1 = aux * 100` the value goes to 7008.49999999. Any one have the solution to it?

Here is my code:

```
        let aux = Double(value)!
        let aux1 = aux * 100
        let aux2 = (aux1).rounded()
        let number = aux2 / 100
        return formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: number))!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to format the Double by rounding it's fraction digits. Try't:

First, implement this method

```
    func formatDouble(_ double: Double, withFractionDigits digits: Int) -> String{
            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.maximumFractionDigits = digits
            let string = formatter.string(from: (NSNumber(floatLiteral: double)))!
            return string

/*if you want a Double instead of a String, change the return value and uncomment the bellow lines*/
            //let number = formatter.number(from: string)!

            //return number.doubleValue
        }
```

after, you can call't that way

```
let roundedNumber = formatDouble(Double(value)!, withFractionDigits: 2)
```

Comment: I've tried this way but it didn't work, so I put `formatter.roundingMode = .halfUp` and now both are working, thanks

Comment: If you let explicit earlier that what your want is rounding to up, maybe that suggestion comes in my mind. 
But i hope it helped you to find a solution.